# Can't run FlexUnit test on android device (run gets stuck on 57%)

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flexunit4

I have a problem with running FlexUnit test (and application in debug mode) on android device.
All fine if I use run project -> export release build and manually send apk to device.
But if I try to run FlexUnit test, the process gets stuck exactly on 57%. If there is no Adobe AIR on my device, Flash Builder tries to install AIR. If AIR is installed on a device, Builder tries to install test application.
But in both cases process gets stuck on 57% without any error.
I've tried to clean project, change workspace, restart my computer, install on different devices and emulators - no luck.
Can you guys advise something?

Some technical details:

FlashBuilder 4.6

Apache Flex 4.15.0

AIR 24.0

AIR on android device 24.0.0.180

Android 6.0, 5.0, 4.4.2